# Get the int value of a query

Tags: c#, database, winforms, int

I have following code.

```
string connStr = String.Format("server=localhost;user id=root; password=1234;" + "database=Printermangement; pooling=false", "localhost", "root", "1234");
string Query = "select sum(Page_Printed) from printjobdetails where User_ID = 'MyProperty'GROUP by User_ID";
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

MessageBox.Show(Query);
```

I want to get the `sum` from this query, but I cannot figure out how to get the `int` value to display in the message box. How can I do this?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(Query);` shows the query, not the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// Prepare the command
string connStr = ...
string Query = "select sum(Page_Printed) from printjobdetails where User_ID = 'MyProperty' GROUP by User_ID";
using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
{
    // Execute the command and get the result
    var sum = (int)cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar();

    // Display the result
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum: {0}", sum));
}
```

I've also placed your command and connection objects within [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks. This will ensure that they are safely closed and any unmanaged resources they use will be disposed of properly.

Answer (score 1):

This example is from [this blog](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/) by Jan Bodnar (very helpful), edited slightly to use `ExecuteScalar()` method to execute the query.

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

public class Example
{

    static void Main() 
    {
        string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=user12;
            password=34klq*;database=mydb";

        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try 
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);

            int sum = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

        } catch (MySqlException ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",  ex.ToString());

        } finally 
        {

            if (conn != null) 
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why `ExecuteReader`? OP just want a single value; `executescalar` is what needed.